# Trying to create mySQL table with JSON_TABLE function but keep getting Error Code 1064

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, split

I'm trying to use the JSON_TABLE function in mysql with the following script but I keep getting this error - "(" is not valid at this position, expecting EOF, ';'

This is on line 2 after json_table at the parenthesis.

```
select * from
  json_table(
    '[{"a":"3"},{"a":2},{"b":1},{"a":0}]',
    "$[*]" columns (id for ordinality,
             jpath varchar(100) path "$.a",
             jexst int exists path '$.b')
  ) as tt;
```

PLease can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here in the above code

Comment: No, I [can't see](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=527cd217cc65020d23a9a34aef101b22) any problem provided that the DB version is 8.

Comment: Thank you for replying Barbaros and yes the DB verison is 8